# Issues with Qt trying to make Darknet with OpenCV support

Tags: opencv, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, darknet

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to `make` [darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) after having successfully installed OpenCV. I have already successfully installed darknet with CUDA support, but I am now trying to empower it with OpenCV, setting `OPENCV=1` in its makefile as indicated in [the official page](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/) ().

This is (an extract) of the output I get from `make`:

```
[...]
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `QWidget::isFullScreen() const@Qt_5'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `QWidget::hasHeightForWidth() const@Qt_5'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `QPen::QPen(QBrush const&, double, Qt::PenStyle, Qt::PenCapStyle, Qt::PenJoinStyle)@Qt_5'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `QStatusBar::showMessage(QString const&, int)@Qt_5'
[...]
```

I get a similar outcome if I try to build some test projects to verify the correct functioning of OpenCV. So I believe the problem lies in some linkage around OpenCV.

It seems `make` does not see Qt libraries in its path. I tried to fix this problem by adding the library folder of Qt5 to both PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40327731/1844776) answer, adding the following lines to my `.profile` file:

```
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export  PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5:$PATH
```

then running `source .profile` and making sure the content was successfully updated with `echo PATH` and `echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The outcome was the same.

Is it possible that the folder I added to the path was incorrect? What else could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the installation of OpenCV. I pulled the latest version of `opencv` and `opencv-contrib` and rebuilt them from scratch, following the [installation instructions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) in detail. After that, I could successfully `make` darknet.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this problem.

Try this:

1. Edit `~/.bashrc` and add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. Save file
3. `source ~/.bashrc`

I think it is because my default installation of qt is in the folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` but it is not linked... so adding it to the path works for me. GL